# How to change field types or field length comfortably in Firebird?

Tags: firebird

I mean, even if the database is empty, you have to drop a varchar(50) field and recreate it to make it varchar(30). Not to mention constraints...

This is very frustrating. I am the SYSDBA and Firebird make very simple things way harder than it should be. If I voluntarily decide to shoot my own feet, then by all means, let me do so!

So how do you do structure changes comfortably in Firebird?

Answer (score 6):

You can't in Firebird.

I advice you to use DOMAIN and smaller size of varchar. If you need to increase the size field : it will be easier.

For your change, you can see [here](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq285/)

Why you have this need ?

Comment: Of course I need this because of changes/dynamics in development. This "feature" makes simple things complex, and it just seems "unfirebird". Look at Firebird: it offers a powerful set of features behind its *simplicity*. It is smart enough to do many things by itself. How much more smartness needed to allow a SYSDBA to change a varchar(50) to varchar(20) in an empty database? Okay, it's not always about varchars in empty databases...but you got the idea. It should have "relaxed mode", some logic or whatever that takes the pain away from structural changes, exclusively for SYSDBA.